# Can Fallout 4 Saves be Uniquely Named?

Tags: fallout-4

Due to the many different branching paths that can be taken I would like to name my saves in a manner that helps me remember what was going on at that point in time that made me want to create a save that I could return to in order to follow a different path.

With the ability to uniquely name pieces of armor and weapons it seems like having the ability to define the name of a save file would be a no-brainer, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do it. At the moment my only recourse is to take a guess, open a save, check out the current missions and try to remember what was happening at that time.

Does anyone know if this is possible and, if it is, can you provide instructions on how to do it? If this is not currently possible, does anyone know where I can go to beg Bethesda to add this functionality in an udpate? Thanks!

Platform: PS4

Comment: It doesn't help that the screenshots in save files almost always show the wrong location so you can't even use a carefully lined up camera angle to remind you why you saved.

Comment: @boomstick Exactly! That's actually a pretty common bug and I bet that Bethesda knows about it, since it's been referenced a LOT of times on all major Fallout 4 communities.

Comment: @boomstick That's interesting. Is that just a PS4 issue? The saves on my Xbox One are a nice photo album. It shoots it in letterbox, with the top and bottom cut off, but the center is just exactly what I was aiming at.

Comment: @DCShannon could be, see e.g. http://i.imgur.com/J9r2eUm.jpg where the "Fort Hagen" saves have pictures of Diamond City, and the "Commonwealth" saves are Nick's office and the Mayor's office. The screenshots seem to lag, showing an earlier location not the correct one when you save. It's quite annoying.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, Fallout 4 doesn't OFFICIALLY support changing the name of the save file. For some reason, Bethesda didn't want to allow us the comfort. On the PC version you can just change the file name, but since you can't do that with the PS4 version, it's not an option.

However, there are some alleged methods of achieving what you want to do. Take a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AI6axX8IrwI) for example. But please be aware that this is always risky and not supported by Bethesda, so if you want to do this, be sure to think twice and double double back-up your progress.

You can use the Feedback section of the Bethesda website to [send a message to the support team of Bethesda](https://help.bethesda.net/app/fallout_feedback%20Fallout%20Feedback), propably the best option for what you want.